# Tabulator - Add subtable to Header of Multi header table

Tags: nested, tabulator, nested-table

I have a tabulator table which has multiple headers with groups, i.e. Title and Sub-Title. I would like to add a subtable to header "Sub Title" listed at this demo.

```
       <https://jsfiddle.net/4gatx38n/1/>
```

[image]

Please let me know how to add?